# Can I animate a circle moving from one point to another with p5.js

Tags: javascript, animation, p5.js

I have two points on my canvas. P0 and P1. I want to move a circle from P0 to P1 with a given time, then repeat the animation. Is this possible to do with p5.js?

Comment: https://p5js.org/examples/hello-p5-animation.html This looks very relevant

Comment: It is possible, all you actually need is a basic trigonometric formula to calculate the distance between p0 and p1 and then make a conditional statement to change the circle direction if it reaches the two ends of both points...and you'll be dividing the current distance from the specified time according to the physics theory on distance calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) for the computation.

Define `P0` and `P1` by [`createVector()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createVector):

```js
P0 = createVector(50, 50);
P1 = createVector(350, 150);
```

Get the start time by [`millis()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis) and compute the end time of the animation in milliseconds:

```js
startTime = millis();
endTime = startTime + 3000; // 3 seconds
```

In [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) get continuously the current time:

```js
let currentTIme = millis();
```

Compute the relation of the passed time and the animation time limit it to a maximum of 1:

```js
let scale = min(1, (currentTIme - startTime) / (endTime - startTime));
```

Compute the vector from `P0` to `P1` and scale it dependent on the passed time:

```js
let V_dist = p5.Vector.sub(P1, P0).mult(scale);
```

Compute the current center point of the animation:

```js
let PX = p5.Vector.add(P0, V_dist);
```

See the example

```js
let P0, P1;
let startTime, endTime;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 200);

    P0 = createVector(50, 50);
    P1 = createVector(350, 150);

    startTime = millis();
    endTime = startTime + 3000; // 3 seconds
}

function draw() {

    let currentTIme = millis();
    let scale = min(1, (currentTIme - startTime) / (endTime - startTime));

    let V_dist = p5.Vector.sub(P1, P0).mult(scale);
    let PX = p5.Vector.add(P0, V_dist);

    background(200);
    
    noFill();
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(3);
    ellipse(PX.x, PX.y, 40, 40)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works great! How would I add a button that started the animation? I tried to edit your example to include one, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @ErikNorberg The button callback has to set `startTime = millis();` `endTime = startTime + 3000;`